# How to exclude specific class using SelectNodes?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using `HtmlAgiliyPack` for take a list of tr from a site. Now on that table there are this rows:

```
<tr class="group-head">
<tr/>
<tr/>
<tr class="group-head">
<tr/>
```

I want get only the tr without the class `group-head` I tried:

```
HtmlNodeCollection rows = doc
           .GetElementbyId("page_player_1_block_player_trophies_5")
            .SelectNodes("//tr[not(@class, 'group-head')]");
```

but this return:

> System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: 'Function 'not' in '//tr[not(@class, 'group-head')]' has an invalid number of arguments.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check for an inequality use

```
//tr[not(@class='group-head')]
```

In the whole expression this is

```
HtmlNodeCollection rows = 
  doc.GetElementbyId("page_player_1_block_player_trophies_5")
     .SelectNodes("//tr[not(@class='group-head')]");
```

Or, if there are more than one strings in the attribute value, use the `contains(...)` function:

```
//tr[not(contains(@class,'group-head'))]
```